# unable to select react id | watir

Tags: watir, watir-webdriver

Hi Fairly new to watir and came across this problem. How can I select the button in the following snippet of code

```
<div id="side bar" class="sidebar">
<div class="inner active" data-reactid=".1">
<a class="back side bar" data-reactid=".1.0" href="#overview">
<h2 data-reactid=".1.1">
<div class="price clearfix" data-reactid=".1.2">
<div class="values type-current-value" data-reactid=".1.3">
<div class="values date-current-value" data-reactid=".1.4">
<div class="values duration-current-value" data-reactid=".1.5">
<div class="values passengers-current-value" data-reactid=".1.6">
<div class="values yacht-current-value" data-reactid=".1.7">
<div class="values flight-current-value" data-reactid=".1.8">
<div class="share-quote" data-reactid=".1.9">
<a class="share-quote cta-button cta-button-blue = share-quote-processed" data-reactid=".1.9.0" data-modal-url="/share-quote" href="#">Share this quote</a>
</div>
```

I am trying the following which produces a no method error

b.links(:xpath => '//div[@class="share-quote"]/a').to_a.click

Answer (score 2):

The code is trying to click an array of links, rather than an individual link. That is why you get an undefined method error.

You need to click a specific link within the collection. For example:

```
# Click the first link
b.links(:xpath => '//div[@class="share-quote"]/a').first.click

# Click the last link
b.links(:xpath => '//div[@class="share-quote"]/a').first.click

# Click the nth link
b.links(:xpath => '//div[@class="share-quote"]/a')[n].click
```

Assuming there is only one of these links on the page, it would be more Watir-like to do:

```
b.div(class: 'share-quote').link.click
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I found that it will only show that link up if the user moves down the page to the relevant section. So currently I have to manually move the vertical scroll otherwise the test will fail.

Comment: There is the question [how to scroll a web page using watir](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13608890/1200545) that can help you with the scrolling question.

Comment: Thanks again for your help